# How many ways we can choose 15 people

Tags: combinatorics

A scientific research institue in the Czech Republic has $30$ members. Ten of them speak English, $8$ speak German, and $12$ speak Spanish. How many ways can choose $15$ people, including at least $2$ people speak English, at least $2$ people speak German, and a maximum of $5$ people speak Spanish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I’d break the count into six cases according to the number of Spanish speakers. If there are $s$ Spanish speakers, then I need to form a committee of $15-s$ people, of whom at least $2$ speak English and at least $2$ speak German. If $s\le 3$, then $15-s\ge 12$, and every committee of $15-s$ people chosen from the English and German speakers will necessarily meet the requirements. That gives me

$$\sum_{s=0}^3\binom{18}{15-s}$$

acceptable committees already.

If $s=4$, so that I must choose a committee of $11$ from the English and German speakers, almost all of the $\binom{18}{11}$ committees are acceptable: only those with all $10$ of the English speakers are not, and there are $8$ of those, for a total of $\binom{18}{11}-8$ acceptable committees in this case.

If $s=5$, there are $\binom{18}{10}$ possible committees, but the one with all $10$ English speakers is unacceptable, as are the $\binom{10}9\binom81$ with exactly one German speaker. The grand total is therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{s=0}^5\binom{18}{15-s}-8-1-\binom{10}9\binom81&=\sum_{k=10}^{15}\binom{18}k-89\\
&=\sum_{k=3}^8\binom{18}k-89\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

(I assume the languages are "disjoint", as the numbers suggest).

The possible combinatons are $2+8+5, 3+7+5,3+8+4,4+6+5,4+7+4,4+8+3,5+5+5,5+6+4,5+7+3,5+8+2,6+4+5,6+5+4,6+6+3,6+7+2,6+8+1,7+3+5,7+4+4,7+5+3,7+6+2,7+7+1,7+8+0,8+2+5,8+3+4,8+4+3,8+5+2,8+6+1,8+7+0,9+2+4,9+3+3,9+4+2,9+5+1,9+6+0,10+2+4,10+3+3,10+4+2$. For each combination $a+b+c$, there are ${10\choose a}{8\choose b}{12\choose c}$ possibilities ...

Answer (score 0):

Potentially-unhelpful sum:
$$
\sum_{\substack{
   a+b+c=15 \\
   a \geq 2 \\
   b \geq 2 \\
   c \leq 5  
  }} \binom{10}{a} \binom{8}{b} \binom{12}{c} 
$$

Which tells you how to get there, but not the answer. Wolfram Alpha suggests that there are 35 different possible (a,b,c) triples.